# AWS CLI Describe VPC peering Requester tag name returns None

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

i am using this command to return the name of the VPC, every option in this query returns the actual value except RequesterVpcInfo.Tags/AccepterVpcInfo.Tags returns None.

```
aws ec2 describe-vpc-peering-connections --query 'VpcPeeringConnections[*].[VpcPeeringConnectionId, RequesterVpcInfo.VpcId, RequesterVpcInfo.Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value | [0]]' --output table
```

Sample output

```
PCX-XXXXX vpc-ddssdd test-vpc
```

tried referring aws docs and even checked stack overflow old problems for solutions but it was of no help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_VpcPeeringConnectionVpcInfo.html), `RequesterVpcInfo` is given by the object `VpcPeeringConnectionVpcInfo` and it does not have the `Tags` key. So, `RequesterVpcInfo.Tags[?Key==Name].Value` will be always `None`.